# Intersection between a function and two lines

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm calculating the intersection between:
$$f(x)= x^2,y=2x-1,y=15-2x$$

I know the intersection between $ x^2$ and $2x-1$ is in $x=1$, and the intersection between $15-2x$ and $2x-1$ is in $x=4$, actually I have this:
[image]

My original idea was calculating the area in this way:

$$\int_{1}^{4} (x^2 - (2x-1))dx$$
but I saw this will include an extra area above the line $y=15-2x$.
How can I calculate the yellow area correctly?

Comment: Which is correct, $y=2x+1$ or $y=2x-1$?

Comment: just edited, is 2x-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection point of $y=x^2$ with $y=2x-1$ is $(1,1)$, and the intersection point of $y=x^2$ with $y=15-2x$  where $x\gt 0$ is $(3,9)$. Also, the intersection point of $y=2x-1$ with $y=15-2x$ is $(4,7)$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Thus, separating the yellow area into red one and green one, we get that the yellow area is given by
$$\int_{1}^{3}(x^2-(2x-1))dx+\int_{3}^4((15-2x)-(2x-1))dx$$

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate piecewise:

The (positive) intersection of $2x-1$ and $x^2$ is at $x=1$.

The  intersection of $x^2$ and $15-2x$ is at $x=3$. And the intersection of $15-2x$ and $2x-1$ is at $x=4$.

Therefore the area is

$\left| \int_1^3 x^2-(2x-1)\, dx \right|+\left| \int_3^4 15-2x-(15-2x)\, dx \right|$

The absolute value signs ensure that the partial areas are positive. This has the advantage that you don´t have to care which of the two functions has to be substracted.